# ASP .NET MVC - how to change view when thread will finished

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, razor, actionresult

I want to make ActionResult with run a thread. When thread are running I will return View with loading but when thread finished the ActionResult return the another View

My code look like:

```
  private static void ExecuteScrapper()
        {
            ScriptEngine pythonEngine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();
            ScriptSource pythonScript = pythonEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/PythonScript/main.py"));

            var searchPath = pythonEngine.GetSearchPaths();
            searchPath.Add(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/PythonScript/"));
            searchPath.Add(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/PythonScript/drivers/"));
            pythonEngine.SetSearchPaths(searchPath);

            var result = pythonScript.Execute();

        }

        private ScrapperEnum.ScrapperOperations scraperParam;

        private Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExecuteScrapper));

        public ActionResult RunScrapper(ScrapperEnum.ScrapperOperations operation)
        {
            scraperParam = operation;
            t.Start();
            bool run = false;

            while(t.IsAlive)
            {
                if(!run)
                {
                    run = true;
                    return View("ScrapperLoadingView");
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Scrapper");
        }
```

I don't know exactly how to do that, because when in this code I return ScrapperLoginView it will break while so the function don't switch the View

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an else if I'm correct

```
     while(t.IsAlive)
                {
                    if(!run)
                    {
                        run = true;
                        return View("ScrapperLoadingView");
                    }

             else 
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Scrapper");
            }
           }
         }
```